# how to change input value if component is using for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

I've a textfield type input box in which I want various type values to enter and when it is of number type the value should increase from the respective function.  I'm getting error `onClick={(event) => handleChange(event)` on this line. Giving error like handleChange is not a function.But at the time of text, it changes according to input value.

```
<TextField
      value="5"
      type={type}
      onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
    />
    {type === "number" ? (
      <Fragment>
        <i onClick={() => handleChange(value+1)} 
        />
        <i onClick={() => handleChange(value-1)} 
        />
      </Fragment>
    ) : null}
```

P.S. I want to increase the value if I click on icon from the textfield.
and this is a handleChange function:

```
handleChange(event, temp) {
const value = event.target.value;
const name = event.target.name;
if (value) {
  handleChange(name, [temp]);
```

}

Comment: Add more clarity to the question, it is not clear what you want to achieve and what is the error?

Comment: handleChange here looks like you are pushing  both an event object, `(event) => handleChange(event)` and a value `() => handleChange(value+1)` which cannot be correct. So, what does the handleChange look like? where does "type" get defined? Need more context.

Comment: 'type' is coming from the backend data. so I'm using 'event' when it is of text type. and I want to increase the value when it is of number type

Comment: What does your handleChange look like?

Comment: 'handleChange' is a common function like onChange where it accepts the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your question is not entirely clear. But ill take a stab at what you might require.

first, lets use the input as a "controlled" component. We can create some state which will hold our current input value..

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(5);
```

We can push `value` to to the TextField using the "value" attribute. We can also capture the value using `setValue` on the `onChange` attribute. Remember that `onChange` returns an object, which we need to get the value from.

```
 <TextField
   value={value}  // <-- the display value set here
   type={type}
   onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}  //<-- the onChange event will update the value through setValue
 />
```

Now, we can also include the extra bits, and mutate the value through the onClick events.

We can set the TextField state using the setValue mutation method.

```
 {type === "number" ? (
        <Fragment>
          <i onClick={() => setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + 1)} />
          <i onClick={() => setValue((prevValue) => prevValue - 1)} />
        </Fragment>
      ) : null}
```

Full Code: ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-mountain-1fkkx?file=/src/App.js:0-626))

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  const type = "number";

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(5);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TextField
        value={value}
        type={type}
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      />
      {type === "number" ? (
        <Fragment>
          <i onClick={() => setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + 1)} />
          <i onClick={() => setValue((prevValue) => prevValue - 1)} />
        </Fragment>
      ) : null}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```